# What Causes the Chapter Title to Get Repeated in the Header

Tags: header-footer, preamble, scrpage2

I've got a rather awkward question. In my preamble there has to be some command that causes the chapter title to be repeated in the header on every commencing page of the chapter.

The following picture shows the issue:
[image: Showing the Issue]

I cannot find out what causes this. Can someone help me find what does?

I am using the following packages which might have something to do with it. However this does not explain why it's placed in the middle of the header.

```
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
```

My full preamble is:

```
%% Ausarbeitung MA Timon Schulz
%% Erstellt am: 31.09.2020
%% Fach: Abschlussarbeit (Master)
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Latex-Packages

\documentclass[11pt,parskip=half,oneside]{scrbook}                                                                      
                                                                                                        %scrbook -->neue Kapitel fangen immer auf rechter seite an

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} % Für Tabellen mit Farbe
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[left=3.0cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}          % Seitenränder
\headsep = 1.5cm
\footskip = 1.5cm
\usepackage{setspace}               % Zeilenabstand 1,5
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}            % Am 29.03.2020 aktiviert. Mal schauen ob es was bringt.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         %Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}                                                 
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{tikz}                   %Für Plots
\usepackage{pgfplots}         %Tikz Package
\usepackage{tikzscale}


% CentimetersTest.tikz
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
%% the following commands are needed for some matlab2tikz features
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\newlength\figurewidth




%\UseRawInputEncoding
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{0,120,113} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc} 

\usepackage{marvosym}               %Für €-Zeichen % finde sonderzeichen über   http://detexify.kirelabs.org %  \EUR
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{gensymb}                %Für °C 
\usepackage{graphicx}               %Für Abbildungen 
\usepackage{pdfpages}               %Für pdf Dateien
\usepackage{epsfig}                 %Ermöglicht Figures im .eps Format (Vectorgrafiken)
%\usepackage{subfigure}             % Ermöglicht ein Subfigures
\usepackage{caption}                    % ermöglicht Umbrüche in Bildunterschriften % \captionsetup{lebelformat=empty} to not show figure number in caption of figure
%\setcapindent{0.5cm}       
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{here}                   % Gleitobjekte "fest setzen"
\usepackage{longtable}              % lange Tabellen über mehrere Seiten
\usepackage{hhline}                 % Doppelter Strich in Tabelle, ähnlich wie \hline \hline
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}       %Für MAthemat. Formeln
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{units}                  %Schreiben von Zahlen mit Einheit mit kleinerem Abstand
\usepackage{wasysym} 
\usepackage{numprint}                                                                                               %\diameter
\usepackage{upgreek}                                                                                                %delta etc.
\usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma,per=fraction,]{siunitx}                     %Hilfreich für schreibweisen
\usepackage{babelbib}                                                                                               %Literatur
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
% Für Lit-Verzeichnis in Inhaltsverzeichnis

\usepackage[]{scrpage2} % Kopf- und Fußzeile footsepline \setfootsepline{.3pt}
\clearscrheadfoot
%\setheadsepline{.3pt}                  % Dicke der Kopfzeile
%\ohead{\pagemark}                  % Fusszeile Mitte Seitenzahl    
\usepackage[version=4,arrows=pgf]{mhchem}       % Chemische Reaktionen
\usepackage{chemformula} % Chemische Reaktionen
\usepackage{chemfig} % Strukturformeln

\usepackage[tracking=true]{microtype}   % Anpassen der Abstände zwischen den Buchstaben für Blocksatz
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}        %Verweise aktivieren; Hidelinks-->  link nicht rot markiert

\usepackage{tabularx} % in the preamble

\usepackage{titlesec}

%\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf} %Für Matlab Grafiken

%% matlab-prettifier
\usepackage[framed, numbered]{matlab-prettifier} %Für Matlab Code
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset{
    literate=% 
{Ö}{{\"O}}1 
{Ä}{{\"A}}1 
{Ü}{{\"U}}1 
{ß}{{\ss}}2 
{ü}{{\"u}}1 
{ä}{{\"a}}1 
{ö}{{\"o}}1
{°}{\textcelcius}1
}

%% Für Plus und Minustoleranzen
\newcommand{\tol}[3]{\ensuremath{\si{#1}^{\ +\num{#2}}_{\ -\num{#3}}\ }}
%Beispiel: \tol{48,00}{0}{0.2}{\mm}


% Landscape Figure / Horizontale Abbildung
%\usepackage{rotating, subcaption} % Package needed for \bigin{sidewaysfigure}[hbt!]
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subcaption} \renewcommand\thesubfigure{\,(\alph{subfigure})}% Basically, a subfigure environment is a minipage, with the added bonus of knowing what to do if it encounters a \caption statement.

\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\DeclareMicrotypeSet*[tracking]{my}     %

{ font = */*/*/sc/* }                   % 
\SetTracking{ encoding = *, shape = sc }{ 45 }  % Hier wird festgelegt, dass alle Passagen in Kapitälchen automatisch leicht gesperrt werden.
%\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} % Verlinkung von Inhalts- und Abbildungsverzeichnis 
%\usepackage[all]{hypcap} 

% Beispiel: Abkürzung => \newcommand{\hmd}[0]{Hausmeisterdienstleistungen}

%"Vorlagen": 

% Abbildungen:
\newcommand{\Abb}[3]{                               % 3 sachen sollen sich ändern können,\Abb{Dateiname}{Bildunterschrift}{labelname}
\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.66\columnwidth]{Figures/#1}                
    \caption{#2}                                    
    \label{#3}  
\end{figure}}   %Diese Arbeit befasst sich mit \hmd{} (HMD)

\newcommand{\F}[1]{\textbf{#1}}     % Fett              Strg + B
\newcommand{\K}[1]{\textit{#1}}     % Kursiv            Strg + I
\newcommand{\U}[1]{\underline{#1}}  % Unterschrichten
%\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\input{Subfiles/#1}} % Verwendung von Sub-Tex-Files

%Umbennenung der Kapitel
\addto\extrasngerman{%
\def\sectionautorefname{Kapitel}%
}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
\def\subsectionautorefname{Kapitel}%
}
\addto\extrasngerman{%
\def\subsubsectionautorefname{Kapitel}%
}

%\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}} % Überschriften nach dem Schema 1.1.1.a
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}} % Überschriften nach dem Schema 1.1.1.1

%Worttrennung--------------------------------------
\hyphenation{Re-aktions-atmos-phäre}

%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Begin des eigentlichen Dokumentes bis /end{document}
\begin{document}  %Begin    
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\maketitle                                         
%Hierfür muss ganz am anfang der titel und autor definiert sein
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Logo auf Deckblatt
%

%% Captions - Tabellen und Abbildungen
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf}}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={bf}}
\setcapindent{0.5cm}

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{Figures/Logos/Logo.jpeg}                    
\end{figure}
%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Deckblatt
%

%% Deckblatt


%% Had to delete some sensitive info here

%% ------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%

\newpage
\pagenumbering{Roman}
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Sperrvermerk
\input{Sperrvermerk.tex}

\newpage
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Ehrenwörtliche Erklärung
\input{Erklaerung.tex}

\newpage
%%____________________________________________________%%%
\input{Widmung.tex}

%%____________________________________________________%%%
\input{Danksagung.tex}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Kurzfassung
\input{Kurzfassung.tex}



%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Formelzeichen
%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Abstract
\input{Abstract.tex}



%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Formelzeichen
\input{Formelzeichen.tex}


%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Abkürzungen
\input{Abkuerzungen.tex}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Englische Begrifflichkeiten
%\input{EnglischeBegrifflichkeiten.tex}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Englische Begrifflichkeiten
%\input{Fachbegriffe.tex}
        
%%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%%% Kurz Glossar
%\input{KurzGlossar.tex}                                                        

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Inhaltsverzeichnis 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % Nummerierungstiefe
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4} % Nummerierungstiefe Inhaltsverzeichnis
\tableofcontents 


%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Aufruf der einzelnen Unterkapitel als .tex_files
% Einzelne Tex-Dokumente auslagern, auch präambel möglich bis auf document classF

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Einleitung.tex}  
\input{Grundlagen.tex}
\input{MaterialUndMethoden.tex}
\input{Ergebnisse.tex}
\input{Diskussion.tex}
\input{Fazit.tex}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%
%% Quellenverzeichnis
%verwende für Literaturliste: pdfLaTex + BibTex

    % Name der .bib Datei
\selectbiblanguage{german}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtdin} % natdin
\newpage
\bibliography{Literatur}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

%% Abbildungsverzeichnis
\newpage
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
%       

\newpage
\input{Anhang.tex}

%%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------%%

\end{document}                  % Abschluss des files
```

Comment: In your code (which is far from minimal...) the line `\pagestyle{scrheadings}` is commented out.

Comment: Thanks. So if I comment it in I get an entire mess because I did not designate an `\ihead{Example Chapter}` to every chapter there is and it continues with the one given before if it does not get a new one. I could now add `\ihead{}` before every chapter. However I discovered that when I comment `\usepackage{scrpage2}`, `\pagestyle{scrheadings}`, `\clearscrheadfoot` out it does put the chapters title in the header still. What causes this? Or is it just some kind of default? I believe what ever causes it interferes with those three packages, which causes other problems.

Comment: It's very difficult to say because (1) this is by no means a minimal example, as I have already said, and (2) your preamble is probably an ancient file inherited from someone who has inherited it from someone else (and so on), which loads lots and lots of old, deprecated and contradictory packages. It would be easier if you could reduce your code and explain exactly the output you expect. Right now it seems that you just want to remove headers altogether, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I know this is not ideal. However I am stuck with this document and cannot produce a minimal example until I know what other packages could have an influence other than the once we already talked about, which is why I'm making this so complicated for you.

My goal is the have headers as depicted in the picture in the question. This seems to be created not only, but also by \usepackage{scrpage2}, \pagestyle{scrheadings}, and \clearscrheadfoot. Would you happen to know which other packages can influence header properties? This would help to reduce the problem.

Comment: Also the page numbers are created by something else and I do not know by what. This might be a hit to somebody more familiar with LaTeX.

Comment: You've got also `titlesec` (and maybe also `tocbibind`) which might mess with headers. And they surely don't work well with `scrbook`. Start deleting everything in the document body (we don't have the files anyway). Delete everything which has to do with chemistry, units, colors, delete all your custom macros. Keep deleting stuff until you arrive at a minimal example showing the problem. If at some point the problem disappears, then you have deleted something which was doing something.

Comment: i am highly suspicious of `\usepackage[]{scrpage2}` and `\clearscrheadfoot`.